# conditional content matching and partial string comparisons using json schema

Tags: jsonschema

I have a case where I need to check the content of one field, based on a partial match (contains) of the content of another field, for validations.

In more specific....if field A contains the string "option 3", and its actually part of a much longer string "Routing Option 3, with user defined....." etc etc and so on...  then I need to check field B to make certain that it contains "more than 1 entry in an array".   If the first check fails, then I need to check and make sure it contains "Exactly 1 entry, and that entry needs to be an empty string"

Here are the requirements in pseudocode

```
If (property A contains "Option 3" [case invariant])
    Validate property B.Length >= 2
else
    Validate property B === [""]
```

Is this complexity of comparison even possible using raw jsonSchema?

Answer (score 1):

You can express your constrain with `if`/`then`/`else`. The pattern would look something like this,

```json
  "if": { "$ref": "#/$defs/is-option-3" },
  "then": { "$ref": "#/$defs/option-3-assertions" },
  "else": { "$ref": "#/$defs/not-option-3-assertions" },
```

The way these keywords work is that if the JSON instance passes validation against the `if` schema, then the it must also pass validation against the `then` schema. If `if` fails, then the instance must pass against the `else` schema.

The `#/$defs/is-option-3` schema can use the `pattern` keyword to assert that property "A" contains "Option 3". You can use the `minLength` and `maxLength` keywords in the other two schemas to make assertions about the string length.